# Get first file of given extension from a folder

Tags: bash

I need to get the first file in a folder which has the `.tar.gz` extension. I came up with:

```
FILE=/path/to/folder/$(ls /path/to/folder | grep ".tar.gz$" | head -1)
```

but I feel it can be done simpler and more elegant. Is there a better solution?

Comment: How do you define "first"? Alphabetical sort, size sort?

Comment: Theoretically the first in alphabetically ascending order, practically there would be a single file of that extension...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could get all the files in an array, and then get the desired one:

```
files=( /path/to/folder/*.tar.gz )
```

Getting the first file:

```
echo "${files[0]}"
```

Getting the last file:

```
echo "${files[${#files[@]}-1]}"
```

You might want to set the shell option `nullglob` to handle cases when there are no matching files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: It seems a bit overkill, my variant has fewer lines although it has some redundant code...

Comment: @AndreiHorak Don't quite understand the question.  If you know the path and the file extension, there are numerous ways that are better than _parsing `ls`_.  For example, `echo /path/*.tar.gz | cut -d' ' -f1` assuming the filenames do not have spaces.

Comment: 2 remarks: 1. to echo the last element of array `files`, the command `echo "${files[-1]}"` will work as well. 2. If there are no files (and `nullglob`) is set, you'll get an error _bad array subscript_. In this case, you might want to replace with `((${#files[@]})) && echo "${files[-1]}"`.

Comment: @devnull That was the question, I know that my approach isn't the best one :) Your example looks better, I will consider it.

Answer (score 12):

here is the shorter version from your own idea.

```
FILE=$(ls /path/to/folder/*.tar.gz| head -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `set` as shown below. The shell will expand the wildcard and `set` will assign the files as positional parameters which can be accessed using `$1`, `$2` etc.

```
# set nullglob so that if no matching files are found, the wildcard expands to a null string
shopt -s nullglob

set -- /path/to/folder/*.tar.gz

# print the name of the first file
echo "$1"
```

It is not good practice to [parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as you are doing, because it will not handle filenames containing newline characters. Also, the `grep` is unnecessary because you could simply do `ls /path/to/folder/*.tar.gz | head -1`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `find` based solution:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.tar.gz" | head -1
```

where:

- `.` is the current directory
- `-maxdepth 1` means only check the current directory
- `-type f` means only look at files
- `-iname "*.tar.gz"` means do a case-insensitive search for any file with the `.tar.gz` extension
- `| head -1` takes the results of find and only returns the first line

You could get rid of the `| head -1` by doing something like:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.tar.gz" -maxdepth 1 -print -quit
```

But I'm actually not sure how portable `-print -quit` is across environments (it works on MacOS and Ubuntu though).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to accomplish it:

```
for FILE in *.tar.gz; do break; done
```

You tell `bash` to `break` the loop in the first iteration, just when the first filename is assigned to `FILE`.

---

Another way to do the same:

```
first() { FILE=$1; } && first *.tar.gz
```

Here you are using the positional parameters of the function `first` which is better than `set` the positional parameters of your entire bash process (as with `set --`).